# Laravel livewire pagination error on mount

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

im trying to retrive the users on page mount and paginate them using the following code:

```php
public function mount()
{
     $this->users = User::where('register_completed', '1')->paginate(16); 
}
```

but im getting this error:

```
Livewire component's [user-search] public property [users] must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]. Only protected or private properties can be set as other types because JavaScript doesn't need to access them.
```

The plan is to load all of the users using `mount` on page load and then let the user filter them using a filter form with multiple criteria. the paginator works using this code:

```php
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.user-search', [
            'users' => User::where('register_completed', '1')->paginate(16),
        ])
            ->extends('layouts.app')
            ->section('content');
}
```

but I need to use a specific function to filter the results based on the selected criteria. also, the search is not real-time and there is a button to call the search filter function.
not sure why pagination only works when passed through the `render` method.
also the `$users` is a public property to access it from the view.

Comment: Please share your complete `UserSearch` Livewire component.

Comment: here it is 
```<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class UserSearch extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public $search;
    public $users;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user-search')
            ->extends('layouts.app')
            ->section('content');
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->users = User::where('register_completed', '1')->paginate(16);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you type-hinted the `$users` property in your Livewire component.
As the error message says, you cannot type-hint a public property to sth. other than `numeric`, `string`, `array`, `null`, or `boolean`.

See the *important notes* from the [Livewire docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties).

Comment: OR one of the following PHP types: Stringable, Collection, DateTime, Model, EloquentCollection. which `$users` fall into this as an EloquentCollection. correct?